# Placing panels alongside each other

Tags: css, html, panel

I am wanting to line two panels up alongside each other.

I currently have one panel (12 wide) which is above and I want two panels to sit below it next to each other to be 6 wide) however the second panel won't line alongside the first panel:

HTML

```css
.panel-heading {
  background: #666;
  color: #FF7800;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.panel-body {
  background: #999;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="panel-heading">Panel Heading</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        Panel Conent
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="panel-heading">Panel Heading</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        Panel Conent
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="panel-heading">Panel Heading</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        Panel Conent
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I have tried floating the panel left but this has no effect, any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: Stop making them into new `div.row` then?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use only one `container`

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="panel-heading">Panel Heading</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                Panel Conent
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="panel-heading">Panel Heading</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                    Panel Conent
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="panel-heading">Panel Heading</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                Panel Conent
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to make new rows for every panel, and you don't need a new container either.

Also, if your goal was to have this be a two-column thing on *all* screen sizes, you need to use the `col-xs-*` classes.

```css
.panel-heading {
  background: #666;
  color: #FF7800;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.panel-body {
  background: #999;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="panel-heading">Panel Heading</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        Panel Conent
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="panel-heading">Panel Heading</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        Panel Conent
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="panel-heading">Panel Heading</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        Panel Conent
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap by default makes a row go full width.

Try moving both 6's into the same row, that should let them sit next to each other.

```
 <div class="container"> 
   <div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-6"> 
<div class="panel-heading">Panel Heading</div>
 <div class="panel-body"> Panel Conent </div> 
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6"> 
<div class="panel-heading">Panel Heading</div> 
<div class="panel-body"> Panel Conent </div>
 </div> 
</div>
</div>
```